# React Uncaught TypeError: this.state.messages.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a React application and I've run into a problem with this mapping function:

```
render() {
    const messages = this.state.messages.map((message) => {
        return (
            <li key={message[".key"]}>{message.text}</li>
        )
    })
    return (...)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.messages.map is not a function

I think it has something to do with the key. My messages state is filled using the `componentDidMount` function with `Firebase`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref("messages/").on("value", (snapshot) => {
        const messages = snapshot.val()
        if(messages != null) {
            this.setState({
                messages: messages
            })
        }
    })
}
```

And messages are added with this function:

```
submitMessage(e) {
    const nextMessage = firebase.database().ref("messages/").push({
        text: this.state.message
    })
}
```

This means my Firebase database with one message looks like this:

```
{
    "messages" : {
        "-KV6trWbEW73p8oS49Qk" : {
            "text" : "test"
        }
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that I am identifying the key incorrectly. Any help with solving this issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the response from the database is an `Object` with keys, whereas [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) needs to be called on an `Array`. The easiest way to loop through an `Object` is to use [`Object.keys(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then use bracket notation to access the values.

```
render() {
    const messages = Object.keys(this.state.messages).map((key) => {
        return (
            <li key={key}>{this.state.messages[key].text}</li>
        )
    })
    return (...)
}
```